# jQuery .sortable() doesnt work with handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a problem that I cant fix. I'd like to move a list of divs (they are created by handlebars)  and sort them, but I am not able to do it and I cant solve.

Here is my code:

```
<script id="template-listado" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <ul>
        {{#each listado}}
        <li id="sortable">
            <div>{{descripcion}}</div>
            <div>{{activo}}</div> 
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" style="width :900px">
  <form name="sinapsis" id="sinapsis" method="post">
  <div class="titulo_pagina">
    <h3>##$ADM_BANNER##</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="listado">
    <script>
      $( "#sortable" ).sortable();      
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

The handlebars script is working fine. This is injected in

Any suggestion??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey the problem has been resolved.

I tried to use the sortable function when the elements werent created yet. I put the jQuery call after  handlebars injection.

```js
init : function(){
     MediaObject.crearObjeto();
     var dlg2 = null;
     this.dlg2 = dlg2 = new DialogBox();
     var navegador = BCheck();
     var formulario = new FormMgr("sinapsis", navegador);

     MediaObject.templateContenido = Handlebars.compile($("#template-listado").html());
     MediaObject.pintarListado();

     $( "#listado > ul" ).sortable();         
},
```